# Where do I find my ftp login details in this scenario?

Tags: asp.net, networking, ftp

Normally when I want to connect through ftp, everything is provided such as the ftp name and username and password by my hosting service. But now I don't have all these details about a local server in my company office because the server is actually not hosting any sites. It's just a server where documents are stored.

But I need a way to connect to this server through my web application.

All I know are:

1. It is possible to connect through remote desktop to that server
2. There is an ip address for that server ( The server machine is in my company office)
3. I have a username and password that allows me to access network drive on that server (I can do this only by directly plugging the cat5 cable to my laptop)

When I configure my outlook email using microsoft exchange server, this is how my settings look like (example.net.au is just for example sake):

Server: server1.example.net.au

User name: jack@example.net.au

Does the ftp detail exist for this server? How do I find out?

Comment: I would appreciate it if you say there is no way to find out based on the information I provided. Anyone knows they can go and talk to their network administrator. I would not even ask that question if that person is still here.

Comment: This is off-topic for [so] as it's not related to programming. Voted to close accordingly.

Comment: FTP is very much related to programming. Regards